Estimate 3D location of a tracked point with Known Camera parameters and Distance
EDIT: Camera has fixed orientation and position with respect to the world coordinates, it is not moving. Therefore, the found [R₁ ∣ t₁] extrinsics are assumed to be constant throughout the moving of X̅₂.
I want to estimate the 3D point of X̅₂,
X̅₂ = [ X₂         Y₂         Z₂ ],
by using known variables:

X̅₁ is at world origin,
camera intrinsics K,
camera extrinsics w.r.t. X̅₁, namely [R₁ ∣ t₁],
euclidean distance d₁₂, between X̅₁ and X̅₂,
image points; x̅₁, x̅₂ tracked by optical flow.

Please check the figure to have visual understanding of the problem.


Can this problem have a solution? 2D-3D mapping might be ill-posed.

How can I formulate this problem?

Do I need to know/calculate R₂ and t₂ extrinsics between camera and X̅₂?

or can I define a cost function to be minimized like this;

ObjFun​ = ∥x₂ − K[R₁ ∣ t₁]X₂∥

subject to d₁₂




We can assume X₂ is 0 to simplify the problem, if necessary.

It is the depth of X̅₂ w.r.t. X̅₁, in world coordinates.



Any ideas/comments would be very appreciated!

EDIT: I have obtained this figure for X̅₂ trajectory, assuming X̅₁ is in the world origin and camera position and orientation is known (known extrinsics), by using Projection Matrix along withRay equation (Multi-view geometry in Computer Vision, Zisserman, page 162), constrained by sphere radius. The info is:

So I've solved X(μ) by X_mu = np.vstack((np.dot(np.linalg.inv(M), (muInit * x - p4)), [1])) w.r.t. μ

I would like to have x-axis of X̅₂ is not positive since it is a known trajectory of boom joints. In other words, it is assumed that boom is not bending so x-axis of X̅₂ cannot be positive. I put this as constraint in the optimization problem, the red 3D points of X̅₂ are the one violating this inequality constraint. Is this error caused by wrong Projection Matrix, P?

Theoretically (meaning, in a perfect universe where your estimates of extrinsics, calibration and flow are exact), the solution is the intersection of the sphere of radius d12 centered at X1, and the ray from the camera backprojecting pixel x2. The sphere has equation:
X.dot(X) = d12**2 

(in numpy notation). The parametric ray's equation is
$\tilde{X}(s) = \tilde{C} + s \cdot R^T \cdot K^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_2[0] \\ x_2[1] \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
You can solve by finding the value of the parameter s that satisfies the sphere's equation. Obviously there are zero, 1 or two solutions, so the problem is in general ill-posed, and you need to inject some priors to restrict the solution to a universe that makes sense for your case.
For example, you may assume that K and the extrinsics are estimated more accurately than the flow (e.g. because they are the result of a very accurate calibration procedure, whereas your optical flow algorithm occasionally smokes some hard stuff). Then an acceptable solution when the ray is outside the sphere may be the point on the sphere that is closest to the ray, i.e. the point on the line passing for X1, orthogonal to the ray, and at distance d12 from X1.
For another example, when you have 2 solutions, you may have extra information telling you that X2 is the closer of the two intersections, e.g., because X1 is "on the floor", and the floor would occlude X2 if it were further than X1 from the camera.
Or something else: understand the context of your problem, work out a solution from that understanding.

Hey @Francesco, thank you for your answer! I see that parametric ray equation looks like the inverse of 3D->2D mapping of the camera. First, R and t you shared in the equation are converting an object point in world coordinate frame to the camera coordinate frame, right? If so, t looks like camera center in the world coordinate system. Second, do you think that [R₁ ∣ t₁] can be used for 2D->3D mapping of the X2, without need of [R2 ∣ t2] ?

Yes to both questions. Please upvote or accept the answers you find useful.

If you are also sure that 't' is the camera center in the equation you shared, can you please edit your answer to avoid confusion? Since 't' is mostly referred as the position of the world origin in the camera coordinate frame, not the camera center.
